# How To Print File Names Conditionally Based On Multiple Imported csv Files

Tags: python, import, filenames

I was wondering if there is a way that prints out the file names conditionally based on the multiple imported csv files. My procedure is:

1. Set my path.
2. Grab all the csv files in this path.
3. Import all these csv files grabbing only the numbers of each file names and store this in 'new_column'.
4. Check number of columns of each file and want to exclude the files that are not having 10 columns (acvhieved using `shape[1]`).
5. Now, **I want to print out the actual file names that don't have 10 columns** -> I am stuck here.

I have no problems up to number 4. However, I am stuck on 5. How do I achieve 5. ?

```
# setting my path
path = r'my\path'

# make a function that grabs all csv files in my path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

# grab the numeric part of each file
def get_numbers_from_filename(filename):
    return re.search(r'\d+', filename).group(0)

# import all the actual csv files and add a 'new_column' column based on the "get_numbers_from_filename" function
li = []
for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
        df['new_column'] = get_numbers_from_filename(filename)
        li.append(df)

# check frequency of column numbers for each file using a frequency table
result = []
for lis in li:
        result.append(lis.shape[1])

# make this a dataframe
result = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = ['shape'])

# actual checking step
result['shape'].value_counts()

# grab only shape == 10 files to correctly concatenate
result = []
for lis in li:
        if lis.shape[1] == 10:
                result.append(lis)

## my solution for part 5:
# print and save all the paths of my directory
path = os.listdir(path)

# grab file names if columns numbers are not 10
result3 = []
for paths in path:
    for list in li:
        if lis.shape[1] != 10:
            result3.append(paths)
```

my solution gives an empty string `[]`

Comment: What is it about part 5 that you are stuck on? Are there any errors, or is there something wrong with what you print out?

Comment: @quamrana I updated my solution to part 5 which gives me an empty string